# Using \vv within in algorithmic

Tags: algorithmic

For the document below, I'm getting errors, shown below, when using `\vv` in the `algorithmic` environment. If I change to `\vec`, there is no error. What can I do to continue using `\vv`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}  
\usepackage{esvect}
\begin{document}
    $\vv{p}$
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \Procedure{$Eval$}{$rm$,$\vv{p}$}

            \EndProcedure
        \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

The errors are:

```
Undefined control sequence. \Procedure{$Eval$}{$rm$,$\vv{p}$}
Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }. \Procedure{$Eval$}{$rm$,$\vv{p}$}
Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete. \Procedure{$Eval$}{$rm$,$\vv{p}$}
Argument of \mathpalette has an extra }. \Procedure{$Eval$}{$rm$,$\vv{p}$}
Paragraph ended before \mathpalette was complete. \Procedure{$Eval$}{$rm$,$\vv{p}$}
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 9.
```

Comment: No, I want to use \vv, not to make \vv behave like \vec

Comment: Using `\Procedure{$Eval$}{$rm$,$\protect\vv{p}$}` seems to work.

Comment: @Noor Ooh, sorry. I thought that `\vv` was undefined. Peter's solution seems to work fine :)

Comment: @PeterGrill yes, it does, what does \protect do, and what was actually the problem ?, would you add an answer so i can mar it as answered ?

Comment: @Noor: egreg has explained it in his answer.

Comment: do you use texstudio?

Comment: The same problem by using $\vv{a}$ in caption of a figure. When I put $\protect\vv{a}$ it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@a ->\@nil 

l.8             \Procedure{$Eval$}{$rm$,$\vv{p}$}
```

The problem is that `\Procedure` has “moving arguments”, so fragile commands such as `\vv` have to be protected. Either use

```
\Procedure{$Eval$}{$rm$,$\protect\vv{p}$}
```

or make the command robust at the outset:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{esvect}

\MakeRobust{\vv}

\begin{document}

$\vv{p}$

\begin{algorithmic}
  \Procedure{$Eval$}{$rm$,$\vv{p}$}

  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In my opinion you should use

```
\Procedure{$\mathit{Eval}$}{$\mathit{rm},\vv{p}$}
```

to get uniform spacing.